# isset() differences between 5.2 and 5.4

Tags: php, httprequest, isset

I seem to be running into an issue where a server running PHP 5.2 that runs the following code fine.

```
<?php

if (isset($mobile , $email , $key , $srcKey) && $srcKey === 'test') {
    echo(sha1(($mobile.$email.$key)));
}
else {
    die('Invalid Values');
}

?>
```

When the following request is posted to the script, everything works fine on my 5.2 server:

```
http://www.test.com/php/script.php?email=caiger01%40hotmail.co.uk&mobile=07446337910&key=xpLOlsGyZq2NM4eYPUVHn8EJ9ahVfj9O&srcKey=test
```

However on PHP 5.4 it seems that the isset statement returns as false regardless?

Comment: Do you have lines above this block like `$mobile=$_POST['mobile']`? Or do you have register globals on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are using register globals, which should not be used and have been deprecated & removed from PHP 5.4.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Wow, that was a great guess!

Comment: No guessing there, it is obvious that the OP is not using the super globals, and is the only explanation as to the behaviour that is seen.

Comment: Maybe it's because I haven't seen a register_globals code in years, I almost forgot that feature; looking at the code I just thought OP had omitted the assignments

Comment: Heh, unfortunately in my day job I have to work with ancient PHP code and handle fixing it to work on the later versions of PHP. PHP Change logs are very useful in this line of work :).

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.4 doesn't have [register_globals](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) which created these variables for you.

The proper way to write this code is:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['mobile'] , $_GET['email'] , $_GET['key'] , $_GET['srcKey']) && $_GET['srcKey'] === 'test') {
        echo(sha1(($_GET['mobile'].$_GET['email'].$_GET['key'])));
    } else {
        die('Invalid Values');
    }
?>
```